# Moving DIV when form expands (transition CSS)

Tags: jquery, css, html

Just writing some CSS and I have a pretty cool Search form where you click on the search icon and it expands out using, "transition: width 0.5 ease-in-out" in CSS.
Great. That works fine.

However, I am planning to put my navigation bar next to the search div on the right of it but of course it will overlap when the user clicks the Search button.
I was wondering if anyone knew of a way where when the Search is expanded, the navigation Div automatically moves to the right with it. I also want the div to revert back to normal when the form loses focus (as the search bar goes back in with the "ease-in-out" function).

I think there maybe some JQuery out there that does it but I really don't know how to write it if there is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is indeed a jQuery method that can help you with this. You can use [jQuery's .animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) to take care of the transition for you.

```
$('#search').click(function() {
    $('#navigation').animate({width: '100px'}, 500);
}
```

This would shrink the width of the navigation to 100px when you click on the search element and animate that transition over 0.5 seconds.

You would probably need to play around with the CSS to stop the flow of your page breaking, but setting the overflow property should take of that quite easily.

Comment: that's a fantastic start! thank you.
the only thing is, I want it to shift the navigation across rather than shrink it. 
i also want it to go back to normal when the form loses focus (that's "onblur" in JS isnt it?)
is it just a case of applying the function to the click event and then applying a reverse animate with the "onblur" event?

Comment: Yes, you can create a similar function with the [blur event](http://api.jquery.com/blur/) with jQuery. Instead of width, change the property that is most appropriate, but without knowing the HTML structure or the CSS, I can't really amend my answer to help you out... having said that, if the navigation was float so that it sat next to the search bar, animating the search bar should move the navigation too and you may not need any JavaScript at all.

Comment: that sounds good! yes the navigation is a left float.
#navigation
{
 position: absolute;
 width: auto;
 height: auto;
 float: left;
 margin: 5px 0 0 35px;
 padding: 5px 0 5px 5px;
}